# Are ICO and Shadow of The Colossus related to each other?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus, ico

Now when the *ICO+Shadow of Colossus Collection* is out for the PS3, I was wondering that are these games some how related to each other? Is it better to play *ICO* first or vice versa?

**EDIT:**
After getting an answer I searched again and found out that Wikipedia has also a small section how these games are connected to each other.

[Wikipedia - Shadow of the Colossus & connections to Ico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus#Connections_to_Ico)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are. *Shadow of the Colossus* is a prequel to *ICO*, set in the same world. In addition, *Shadow of the Colossus* explains some of the story from *ICO*. So I would recommend playing *Shadow of the Colossus* before starting *ICO*.

Comment: Thank you! I really like to play game series in correct order without skipping any earlier games (with some exceptions).

Comment: It's kind of a stretch to imply that SotC *explains* anything. But it's certainly true that an understanding of events from SotC will inform a play through of Ico in interesting ways...

Answer (score 7):

SotC and ICO's connection as well as timelines are left up to personal interpretation. The games' creator has gone on record saying he had no idea in mind as to how they both intertwine while creating them other than the fact they both take place in the same world.

Most fans believe SotC is a prequel due to the ending which reveals a baby with a "certain condition".

Have a look at this (slightly spoiler laden) [bit from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Colossus#Connections_to_Ico):

> Shadow of the Colossus is considered both a spiritual successor
>   and prequel to Ico. For several months during and after the game's
>   release, the game's director and lead designer, Fumito Ueda,
>   maintained that the game's status as a prequel was simply his personal
>   take on the game and not necessarily its canon nature, as he largely
>   intended for players to decide the specifics of the story for
>   themselves, but he confirmed the two do have a connection.
>   Moreover, the shadowy figures which appear in the Shrine of Worship
>   are connected to the shadows which the player must fight in Ico.
>   Both games feature "horned" characters for protagonists (Wander
>   sprouts horns at the end of the game). The Queen's Sword from Ico is
>   also available as a bonus unlockable item. Both games also use
>   unique fictional languages.

Answer (score 0):

The games are connected and also in the book if you consider that relevant to this explains there are many people that have had horns and by icos time they are being sacrificed so in order for there to be so many I think that ico is a few hundred years after shadow of the colossus